# CDK or CloudFormation resource for adding SSH key to IAM user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm unable to locate in the docs how to specify an IAM user's public SSH key in AWS CDK and can't seem to find the corresponding CloudFormation type either. Terraform has the following:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_user_ssh_key

How do I specify the key in either CloudFormation or CDK?

Comment: I see you made new question about custom resource. This is exactly what my answer suggested yet you haven't accepted my answer. May I ask why?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Got it working with AwsCustomResource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not supported**. You would have to develop your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) for that.